# Find the Maximum of an input vector in verilog

Tags: max, verilog, system-verilog

Im trying to get the maximum of an input vector. Im assuming all inputs are unsigned and that it should work on a range of bitwidths and array lengths.
I have to keep the parameters and input and output logic the way they are. Here is what I have, but I get a syntax error at the if statement:

```
module max
 #(parameter int bW=16,
   parameter int eC=8)
  (input logic [bW-1:0] a[eC-1:0],
   output logic [bW-1:0] z);

 logic i=0;

 always @* begin

   for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
         if(a[i] >z)
             z = a[i];
       }
 end
endmodule
```

Maybe using a case statement would be better? I dont know. Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Two simple problems.

You used brackets `{/}` instead of `begin`/`end` to wrap your looping statement. No need to wrap a single statement anyways.

You defined `i` as a single bit. use an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to use a default for the initial value, then compute max from there.

For example:

```
module max
 #(parameter int bW=16,
   parameter int eC=8)
  (input logic [bW-1:0] a[eC-1:0],
   output logic [bW-1:0] z);

 always @(*) begin
   // defaults 
   z = 0;

   for (int i=0; i<size; i++) begin
       if (a[i] > z)
           z = a[i];
   end
 end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, I believe the for comparison value should be 'eC', not 'size'.  This compiles for me (with the sverilog flag of course):

```
module max #(
    parameter int bW = 16,
    parameter int eC = 8
)
(
    input  logic [bW-1:0] a [eC-1:0],
    output logic [bW-1:0] z
);

always @* begin

    z = a[0];
    for (int i=1; i<eC; i++) begin
        if(a[i] > z) begin
            z = a[i];
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```